# status of C++23 formatting ranges

Tags: c++, c++23

I watched [Barry Revzin's talk on Formatting Ranges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQELdyecZlU&t=3069s) that was very interesting.
I see the [feature status page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) that Formatting Ranges is still planned for C++23, ad it says clang has implemented it.

But when I try some of Barry's examples on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sd4813G3P)(with -std=c++2b), I get compiler errors, and today getting core dumps.

Plus when Googling around, I don't see many talking about it. I don't even see much on [cppreference](https://duckduckgo.com/?sites=cppreference.com&q=range_formatter&ia=web)?

Understandably the release isn't complete, but seems odd that documentation is lacking, and nobody is taking about it?

- not much chatter about it
- Godbolt isn't compiling
- not much documentation on CppReference

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387964/997587

Comment: Have you tried with [g++](https://godbolt.org/z/cjrz6d7T3)?

Comment: Sorry Richard, fixed the link; https://godbolt.org/z/sd4813G3P

Yes, it says only clang has implemented it, but I have tried the main 3 compilers without success. gcc does not even know the <format> header.

Comment: I can understand things not being fully implemented, even on Godbolt trunks. But since there isn't much chatter, and I don't even see it fully documented on CPPreference or anywhere else except for the CPP submissions, I'm curious abut why there isn't more interest?

Comment: Also, trying a link from 
[cppstories](https://www.cppstories.com/2022/custom-stdformat-cpp20/)
that looks at a MSVC example
[MSVC godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3zaWjWsf9)
that causes a fatal error.

As I said, is it an odd coincidence that a feature is causing multiple compilers to crash - or is something else causing this feature to crash on multiple compilers?

Comment: The MSVC Godbolt example works fine when run locally. So you might have found a Godbolt problem? Also, MSVC lists `<print>` as implemented in v17.7, which is two releases from now.

Answer (score 1):

Range formatting is a part of C++23 and [documented at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/range_formatter#Range_format_specification).

Your pair example is incorrect since pairs don't support format specifications for their elements which is why it won't compile even with libc++ that claims to implement range formatting. libstdc++ and Microsoft STL don't (fully) support range formatting yet.